# Regarding user in salesforce

Tags: apex, user

while inserting user object data in Test Class

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Locale: bad value for
>   restricted picklist field: English(Ireland,Euro): [LocaleSidKey]

how to insert localesidkey and Locale Value for user using apex class

Comment: Can you post your code where you set the `User` object. Also try `English(Ireland)` for Locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an example of how create a user in apex

**Example:**

```
 Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
        User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com');
```

List of Locales and corresponding codes (LocaleSidKey) with its formats for Date, Names and Numbers can be found in [Supported Locales](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&language=en).

Comment: Thx @vigneshwaran-g for add the list of supported locales.